# Macbook shutting down after a screen glitch

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My 13" MacBook Pro (Late 2017) with MacOS 11.4 started to behave weirdly today:
[image]

After a few seconds, it goes black, just like it was turned off – but it is not. I have to turn it off by long-pressing the power button, and then I can bring him back to life.

I was having another screen plugged in the first time it happened and the glitch appeared first on the screen, and then after ~5 seconds on my MacBook' screen.

What might be the reason for such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the first thing I would have advised is to plug in an external monitor. *Whoops* you already have done that.

So if that happens on both internal and external displays it is not the display itself. Instead I would tend to blame the GPU (graphics hardware subsystem). Especially as the system doesn't shut down, rather it has to be manually shut down.

That said it *might* be worth your while to back up your system, wipe the drive and reinstall macOS. If the problem does not return well I was wrong and it was something in macOS causing this.

But honestly too many years doing computer support for a living it *smells like* a hardware issue. So it may require repairs at your local Apple repair shop.

Comment: I've just got it back from a repair. They did not find anything though – hardware is OK, and software seemed OK as well. However, what I found after launching it back is that it happens on my account. Seems that the spotlight is reindexing the files and it causes the mac to freeze and shut down. I've disabled the reindexing with `sudo mdutil -a -i off` and am now seeking some help how to actually reindex it from the ground up

Comment: Glad to hear it! Try this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/spotlight-indexing-appears-stuck-what-can-i-do

Comment: For anyone with the same problem – unfortunately in my case it was the logic board, and I had to get it replaced.